# How to iterate over std::vector<char> and find null-terminated c-strings

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have three questions based on the following code fragments
I have a list of strings. It just happens to be a vector but could potentially be any source

```
vector<string> v1_names = boost::assign::list_of("Antigua and Barbuda")( "Brasil")( "Papua New Guinea")( "Togo");
```

The following is to store lengths of each name

```
vector<int> name_len;
```

the following is where I want to store the strings

```
std::vector<char> v2_names;
```

estimate memory required to copy names from v1_names

```
v2_names.reserve( v1_names.size()*20 + 4 );
```

**Question:** is this the best way to estimate storage? I fix the max len at 20 that is ok, then add space for null treminator
Now copy the names

```
for( std::vector<std::string>::size_type i = 0; i < v1_names.size(); ++i)
{
    std::string val( v1_names[i] );
    name_len.push_back(val.length());
    for(std::string::iterator it = val.begin(); it != val.end(); ++it)
    {
        v2_names.push_back( *it );
    }
    v2_names.push_back('\0');
}
```

**Question:** is this the most efficient way to copy the elements from v1_name to v2_names?
 
**Main Question:** How do I iterate over v2_names and print the country names contained in v2_names

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What is the problem with storing a `vector<string>`? You might end up making the solution exceedingly complex for no reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To estimate storage, you should probably measure the strings, rather than rely on a hard-coded constant 20. For example:

```
size_t total = 0;
for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = v1_names.begin(); it != v1_names.end(); ++it) {
    total += it->size() + 1;
}
```

The main inefficiency in your loop is probably that you take an extra copy of each string in turn: `std::string val( v1_names[i] );` could instead be `const std::string &val = v1_names[i];`.

To append each string, you can use the `insert` function:

```
v2_names.insert(v2_names.end(), val.begin(), val.end());
v2_names.push_back(0);
```

This isn't necessarily the most efficient, since there's a certain amount of redundant checking of available space in the vector, but it shouldn't be too bad and it's simple. An alternative would be to size `v2_names` at the start rather than reserving space, and then copy data (with `std::copy`) rather than appending it. But either one of them might be faster, and it shouldn't make a lot of difference.

For the main question, if all you have is `v2_names` and you want to print the strings, you could do something like this:

```
const char *p = &v2_names.front();
while (p <= &v2_names.back()) {
    std::cout << p << "\n";
    p += strlen(p) + 1;
}
```

If you also have `name_len`:

```
size_t offset = 0;
for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = name_len.begin(); it != name_len.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << &v2_names[offset] << "\n";
    offset += *it + 1;
}
```

Beware that the type of `name_len` is technically wrong - it's not guaranteed that you can store a string length in an `int`. That said, even if `int` is smaller than `size_t` in a particular implementation, strings that big will still be pretty rare.

Comment: I was hoping you could use the information stored in `name_len` to compute the offsets but couldn't find a workable way to do this

Comment: @samra: ah, so you have `name_len` and `v2_names` to hand. OK, I'll edit.

Comment: Only you seem to have read (and understood ) the entire question(s) and answered them all. Thanks

Comment: I have trouble understanding this expression `offset += *it + 1`. Can you simplify it for me? May be a loop in terms of indexes as opposed to iterators. I have trouble doing arithmetic on iterators

Comment: `*it` is the value referred to by the iterator, that is to say it's an element of `name_len` and hence the length of a string. `*it+1` is the size including the nul terminator. `offset += *it + 1` adds that size to the current offset.

Answer (score 2):

Use simple join, profit!

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/join.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char **)
{
    vector<string> v1_names = boost::assign::list_of("Antigua and Barbuda")( "Brasil")( "Papua New Guinea")( "Togo");

    std::string joined = boost::algorithm::join(v1_names, "\0");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to compute the required storage is to sum up the length of each string in `v1_names`.

For your second question instead of using the for loop for you could just use the `iterator, iterator` append method of vector with `begin` and `end` on the string.

For your third question: Just don't do that. Iterate over `v1_names`'s strings instead. The only reason to *ever* create such a thing as `v2_names` is to pass it into a legacy C API and then you don't have to worry about iterating over it.

Comment: I really do want to iterate over v2_names. Infact that is the main question. v1_names is just an example of one source of my strings. The target is v2_names.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to concatenate all the strings, you could just use a single pass and rely on amortized O(1) insertions:

```
name_len.reserve(v1_names.size());

// v2_names.reserve( ??? ); // only if you have a good heuristic or
                            // if you can determine this efficiently

for (auto it = v1_names.cbegin(); it != v1_names.cend(); ++it)
{
  name_len.push_back(it->size());
  v2_names.insert(v2_names.end(), it->c_str(), it->c_str() + it->size() + 1);
}
```

You *could* precompute the total length by another loop before this and call `reserve` if you think this will help. It depends on how well you know the strings. But perhaps there's no point worrying, since in the long run the insertions are O(1).